# How to indicate hierarchy from left sidebar list -> horizontal top tabs

Tags: gui-design, hierarchy

I have a desktop (i.e. *not* mobile) app with an overall **two level hierarchy**:

Items -> Dimensions

Typical number of items/dimensions:

- Items: 2-40
- Dimensions: 3-4

Item 2 -> Dimension *A* is of the same type as Item 6 -> Dimension *A*.
That is, Dimension *A*'s are like apples and apples. Not apples and oranges...

The UI should support quick and easy navigation between Dimensions of different Items.

### A: Accordion

An accordion would be a UI solution, see A in wireframe below.

Advantages:

- Hierarchy is very clear

Problems:

- Accordion headers jump up and down
- List of Items become more "complex"

### B: List + tabs

would be another solution, see wireframe below.

Advantages:

- List Items and tabs stay in place

Problems:

- Hierarchy is not immediately understandable.

I personally prefer B: List + tabs due the stay-in-place advantage stated above, so

### My question is:

> **In B (see wireframe below): How do I clearly indicate that tabs are sublevels of the list selection?**

[image: Accordion -versus- List + tabs]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve it by encapsulating the tabs:

[image]

(Plus, gegarding the number of the items, you coul still use some grouping of them.)

Comment: Nice idea and mockup! A challenge is, though, that the list of Items may grow to the extent that a vertical scrollbar appears on the right thus visually "detaching" the selected Item from the tab space on the right. However, using a bit of padding to the overall tabs container and applying the same background color to that as to the selected Item might do the trick.

Comment: Yes, and another way to do it would be grouping items - if possible, of course (just try to visualize the list of items split into groups - might work, but would need some nice idea to implement it visually).

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the basic, well understood treeview:

[image: a tree view hierarchy]

The advantage is that it's a well established convention that most computer users already understand how to use and the hierarchy is crystal clear. I suppose in your case there's a disadvantage of the subitem type (dimension) not being very apparent, but that could be mitigated by styling the subitems to indicate their type. E.g. dimensions of type A could have a red background, type B could have as blue background, etc. or each dimension could have their own icon, or use both color and icon.

Comment: You're right, a treeview is familiar to most people. However, the interaction/navigation quickly becomes fiddly with expanding and collapsing back and forth. Furthermore, I believe it would be overkill in this situation with only to overall levels, Items and Dimensions.